# Mysterious login attempts showing in SQL Server logs

Tags: sql-server, virtual-machine, clone

I made a VM clone of a SQL Server 2012 install. Now on the original install, the SQL Server log is showing login attempts by the clone server.

OLDSERVER was cloned to NEWSERVER, along with SQL 2012 database.
In OLDSERVER logs there are error messages (two per minute) that read:
"Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\NEWSERVER$'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: 10.x.x.xxx]. Error: 18456. Severity 14. State: 5."

I am glad the login is failing because I do not want NEWSERVER connecting to the old database. My question is, what process on NEWSERVER is trying to connect to the OLDSERVER SQL database? How do I find it, and shut it off?

Comment: Did you set up remote procedure calls on OLDSERVER that target itself?

Comment: Any SQL Agent jobs that could be responsible?

Comment: Not that I know of. The database is basically idle (no users actively using it). But the logins attempts persists every minute, according to the log.

Comment: Regarding SQL Agent jobs, I de-activated the backup jobs that were scheduled to run once per day. There are a few other jobs, but they do reference NEWSERVER under the connection area.

Comment: I believe I uncovered the problem. The Report Services was trying to connect through the OLDSERVER Report Services database. After changing it to NEWSERVEr Report Services, the logs stopped reporting the login error.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I uncovered the problem. The Report Services was trying to connect through the OLDSERVER Report Services database. After changing it to NEWSERVER Report Services, the logs stopped reporting the login error.